# Merge two array into one array with key value relationship

Tags: javascript

Javascript:
 I have two arrays. one with key other one with value.. i need to merge them together in key value pairs into one array.

```
arr2 = ["anik","manik","philip"];
arr1 =[1,2,3];

how to make 
resultArray = ["anik:1","manik:2","philip:3"];
```

### Edit 1

#### Tried

```
        Array.prototype.associate = function (keys) {
            var result = {};

            this.forEach(function (el, i) {
                result[keys[i]] = el;
            });

            return result;
        };
        var customerId = arr2;
        var customerName = arr3;
        console.log(customerId.associate(customerName));
        console.log(Object.keys(arr));
        //document.getElementById(customerId.associate(customerName));
```

### Solved

```
 array3 = [];
            console.log(arr2);
            arr2.forEach(function (e, i) {
                array3.push(
                  [e] + ":" + arr3[i]
                );
            })

            document.write(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

Comment: plz check my edit i tried something

Comment: What is `arr`, `arr2`, `arr3`? Your first example does not line up with your second example at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.
`array3` will be the desired result.

```js
array1 = ["anik", "manik", "philip"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3];
array3 = [];

array1.forEach(function(e, i) {
  array3.push(
    e + ":" + array2[i]
  );
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

**This is the better way:**

```
var array1 = ["anik", "manik", "philip"];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3];

var array3 = array1.map(function(e, i) {
  return e + ":" + array2[i];
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

Comment: `forEach` + `push` is like reinventing `map`. The array notation with `[e]` is very wasteful as well, since it creates a new array every iteration, before coercing it into a string.

Comment: @Oka Thx. I have changed the `[e]`. That was a relict from another atempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = ["anik","manik","philip"];
var values = [1,2,3];
var results = keys.map(function(k, index){
  return {[k]:values[index]}
});
console.log(results);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3phx9fw/)