# Multiple JS object merged with keys in one

Tags: javascript

I need to transform 3 js objects in one object.
I have this vars with same length:

```
var date = ["2020-10-09", "2020-10-15", ...]
var count= [2, 5, ...]
var name= ["Ivan", "Maria", ...]
```

I want to transform the three vars in this structure:

```
 var alldata = [
    {
        "date": "2020-10-09",
        "count": 2,
        "name": "Ivan"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-10-15",
        "count": 5,
        "name": "Maria"
    }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array into one array with key value relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523863/merge-two-array-into-one-array-with-key-value-relationship)

Comment: as StackOverflow is not a "please code this for me", but rather a help platform, did you achieve anything yet that you can share with us ?

Comment: (If it does, be sure to give it an upvote!).

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Even if it is inefficient or not working. Loop through one of the arrays and create an object. Access other arrays using the same index to get the corresponding value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var count= [2, 5]
var name= ["Ivan", "Maria"]
let employee = [];
for (let i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
  employee.push(
    {
      date:date[i],
      count:count[i],
      name:name[i]
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var date = ['2020-10-09', '2020-10-15'];
var count = [2, 5];
var name = ['Ivan', 'Maria'];

const alldata = Array.from({
  length: Math.max(date.length, count.length, name.length),
}).map((_, i) => ({ date: date[i], name: name[i], count: count[i] }));
console.warn(alldata)
```

or in you case that you know they are the same length

```js
var date = ['2020-10-09', '2020-10-15'];
var count = [2, 5];
var name = ['Ivan', 'Maria'];

const alldata = date.map((_, i) => ({
  date: date[i],
  name: name[i],
  count: count[i],
}));
console.warn(alldata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ["zip"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)) the two arrays, and for each zipped array, you can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on the zipped arrays. `Object.fromEntries()` takes an array of key-value pairs, which you can produce by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each array to an array of key `[key, value]` pairs like so:

```js
const date = ["2020-10-09", "2020-10-15"];
const count =  [2, 5];
const name = ["Ivan", "Maria"];

const arrs = [date, count, name];
const keys = ["date", "count", "name"]; // key name for each array
const res = arrs[0].map(
  (_, i) => Object.fromEntries(arrs.map((r,j)=>[keys[j], r[i]])
));

console.log(res);
```